How to restrict members in Azure viewing Azure Directory

Would it be possible in AzureAD to prevent "guests or members" to have access viewing users in AzureAD? I was able to try it in guests by going to User settings > Restrict Guest from viewing directory, but there's no option for members.
In the conditional access, I've tried it as well but it's blocking the whole admin portal.
What I only want to achieve here is that not admin users should not be able other users in users directory.

Navigate to Entra -> Users -> Users settings -> Restrict access to Microsoft Entra Admin Center

